# Wrong use of stringification

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

Given the following code:

```
#define MY_STRINGIFY_MACRO(...) #__VA_ARGS__

#define PORT_MAC(portNum) port: portNum

#define LOG_MACRO(...)
     printf( MY_STRINGIFY_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__) ) 

void func(int portNum)
{
    LOG_MACRO( PORT_MAC(portNum) ); /* In a more general way I would use this macro as LOG_MACRO( PORT_MAC(portNum), PORT_MAC(portNum1) ... ); to get output of " port: 2, port: 3 ... "*/
}
```

When `func()` is called with a port number, for example `2`, the output is:

```
 port: portNum
```

instead of

```
 port: 2
```

And if I use the macro the following way:

```
 LOG_MACRO( PORT_MAC(2) );
```

Then I get the desired output:

```
 port: 2
```

How can I fix my code so that it could handle both cases and the output will always contain the `portNum` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem confused about compile-time vs runtime.

A macro runs at compile time (before anything else is done to your code). That's when the replacement happens. At this point, the only thing CPP (the C Pre Processor) considers is text. It doesn't see anything else (and doesn't even care for it to be valid C code!). Then your code is compiled and you get your binary file (`a.out` by default).

At this point, no code was **executed**. No functions were called. Only by the time you launch your program (`$ ./a.out`) are functions called, and parameters passed. What you want to do is not possible. Your only option is to replace in the text at runtime.

Comment: `Your only option is to replace in the text at runtime` can you explain?

Comment: You have a `const char *` (that you're passing to `printf`). You need to replace the value "manually" (don't forget to duplicate the string before. Modifying a `const char*` will probably result in a segfault). Another way would be to call `LOG_MACRO(PORT_MAC(%d), portNum)`. But that'd mean `LOG_MACRO` isn't allowed to use `__VA_ARGS__` (because you need to pass `__VA_ARGS__` to printf)